# No visible @interface for 'HODatabasesManager' declares the selector 'db'

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

The error is: No visible @interface for 'HODatabasesManager' declares the selector 'db'.

```
#import "BaseDB.h"

@implementation BaseDB

- (void)executeInBackgroundSuccess:(void (^)(id))success {
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue(), ^{
        id result = [self executeQuery];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            if (success) {
                success(result);                
            }
        });
    });
}

- (FMDatabase *)fmDatabase {
    return [[HODatabasesManager shareInstance] db];
}

- (id)executeQuery {
    return nil;
}

dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue() {
    static dispatch_once_t queueCreationGuard;
    static dispatch_queue_t queue;
    dispatch_once(&queueCreationGuard, ^{
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("vn.conglv.dbqueue", 0);
    });
    return queue;
}
@end
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `db` declared in the header file of `HODatabasesManager`?